# Cocos2d synchronise a sprite with another sprite's animation

Tags: ios, animation, cocos2d-iphone

I am trying to create a sprite animation of a character firing a gun in Cocos2d. I am struggling to find a way to instantiating and start moving the bullet sprite at the appropriate frame of the load/aim/fire animation of my character.

For example, my character goes through an 12 frame animation to fire his gun and the bullet should be released at frame 7.

Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance
Al

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way of doing this, a similar scenario in a game i am developping. I want , on frame 10 of 16, to schedule an 'attackTurnAround' method (to animate damage animations, hurt on the victim, etc...). Dont waste time on 'frame notifications', sometimes a frame will be skipped, and you will end up with no notifications.

caveat : timing is key. Before getting at this point, i preload EVERYTHING that will happen in 'attackTurnAround' , namely the hurt (or dead) animation, the damage animation, the soundFx that will be heard when the sword hits on frame 10, etc .....

```
BattleAnimation *ba = [self attackerAttackAnination];
_attackerAttackSprite = ba.firstSprite;
[_attackerNode addChild:_attackerAttackSprite];
CCActionAnimate *anim     = [CCActionAnimate actionWithAnimation:ba.animation];
id              endAttack = [CCActionCallBlock actionWithBlock:^{

    [self endAttack];
}];
id              seq       = [CCActionSequence actions:anim, endAttack, nil];
_attackerAttackSprite.visible = YES;
_attackerIdleSprite.visible   = NO;
[_attackerAttackSprite runAction:seq];
[self scheduleOnce:@selector(attackTurnAround) delay:9. * ba.duration / 16.];
```

Comment: Thanks YvesLeBorg, the caveat about timing being key (rather than using the animation frame number) makes complete sense. I'll give it a go. Cheers !!